# OpenGL in XNA is it possible?

Tags: opengl, xna

I was wandering is there a way to work in XNA using OpenGL, this is not counting Xamarin products, and if it is, is there any tutorials of how to set XNA libraries or whatever it uses. I need such combination to start working on I projects until I buy MonoDroid, so the projects with effects be easily ported to Android.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft XNA is a framework built upon DirectX; you cannot just run it upon OpenGL.
Long answer to your question: you should look at MonoGame (http://monogame.codeplex.com/): it is an open source replacement for XNA, which runs on many platforms.

It is not XNA (you will need to retarget your project to MonoGame, IIRC), but it is almost a drop-in replacement (there are many success stories of porting games in minutes to hours).

Answer (score 2):

XNA is DirectX only. If you want to use OpenGL on .NET, there are multiple libraries for this:
[OpentTK](http://www.opentk.com/) (the most popular) or [SharpGL](http://sharpgl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I also used TAO, in the past. However, it seems to me that the OP would like to use XNA, and just use OpenGL as a lower layer to improve portability, as an alternative to target OpenGL directly.

Comment: Also, most of these libraries are just thin managed wrappers upon unmanaged OpenGL dlls; they may not work on non-win32 systems

Comment: that should be openTK, and the link should point to www.opentk.com